# how to avoid bullets showing in main menu

Tags: css, wordpress

i am working on a WordPress site, and my initial problem was that when i had a bullet, the text would wrap around it such that some text was below the bullet point and so i wanted to align my bullets such that when text is wrapped it doesn't show below the bullet point,

so i did this in my custom css

```
ul {
list-style-type: circle;
    list-style: outside;
   padding-left: 20px;
}
```

which worked great except now i have bullets appearing next to the links on the drop down part of my menu, how can i exclude the code from affecting the main menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ul {
    list-style-type: circle;
    list-style: outside;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

#site-header ul{
    list-style:none;
}
```

Write a specific selector for the site-nav ul list and remove the styles. Adding the #site-header before ul will overwrite the original statement for that element. Effectively, this will apply your original style to all ul elements except the ones in #site-header

I believe wp adds #site-header automatically to the main header element. If this is not the case for your theme, just change #site-header to any parent element id specific to your header.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you're using ul as your selector.  This will apply those styles to ALL ul elements in your page.  If you want to only select a single ul, you can either add an id or class to it, or you can select it's container, such as

```
div ul { // styles here }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to be more specific on your css rule, otherwise you're aplying that style to all your ULs

`#parentElement ul {
    list-style-type: circle;
    list-style: outside;
    padding-left: 20px;
}`

Answer (score 0):

instead of creating that `list-style-type` for all ul, just create it for the specific one you want to appear the bullets. Otherwise find the main menu id and add this: `list-style-type: none;`